# How can I run android emulator without having `adb` or platform-tools?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, adb

I want to run `android-studio` emulator without having an `adb`.

On running the emulator It checks for the adb.exe using `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` environment variable and exits if there is no valid one(valid one = having an `adb`).

How to run the emulator without having the `adb`? Is there a command enabling running the emulator without the `adb` or something like that?

Comment: like this one for instance? https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline

Comment: @Lino yeah. but this doesn't contain a parameter (or anything else) to disable the adb.